# Lambda Expression reduction to NF

Tags: lambda, lambda-calculus, chomsky-normal-form

I need to reduce the following Lambda expressions into Normal Form, using Normal Order. These are my reductions but they don't make sense to me:

```
//First expression
(λf.λx.f(fx))(λy.+y1)(+ 2 3)
(λx.fx)(λy.+y1)(+ 2 3)
f(λy.+y1)(+ 2 3)
f(+(+ 2 3) 1)
f(+ 5 1)
f 6

//Second expression
λx. + ((λy.((λx.∗ xy) 2)) x) y)
+((λy.((λw.* wy) 2) w)
+((λw.* ww) 2)
+(* 2 2)
+ 4
```

Both NF that I got make no sense. The second one is a + function which requires 2 variables but ends up with only one.

I would appreciate any suggestions and corrections.

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
//First expression
(λf.λx.f(fx))(λy.+y1)(+ 2 3)
```

I think your mistake here is thinking that the first term can be reduced. I don't think it can, so start applying it to the other terms right away.

2.

```
//Second expression
λx. (+ ((λy.((λx.∗ xy) 2)) x) y)
```

To reduce this start by applying the innermost term and renaming the last `y` so you get:

```
λx. (+ ((λy.(∗ 2y)) x) w)
```

Then continue :)